# Fastest way to transfer/copy data from float* to vector<float>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a float* variable. I want to copy the value in the float* to the vector . Could you suggest the fastest way to do it on C++?
This is my baseline code

```
std::vector<float> CopyFloat2Vector(float* input, int size1) {
  std::vector<float> vector_out;
  for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {  
    vector_out.push_back(input[size1 + i]);    
  }
  return vector_out;
}
```

I also tried memcopy but it does not work

```
float* input =....; //I have some value store in input with size of 1xsize1
std::vector<float> vector_out;
memcpy(vector_out.data(), input, size1 * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Resize or reserve your vector.

Comment: `reserve()` or `resize()` the vector before you use the first loop, and if you resize don't use `push_back()` just assign the values. `resize()` the vector before you `memcpy`. Another way is to let the vector deal with it. `std::vector<float> v(input, input + size);`

Comment: Thanks so much. I will add resize before memcpy. Which one is faster memcpy or my function CopyFloat2Vector?

Comment: The fastest and shortest IMHO `std::vector<float> vector_out(input, input + size1);`

Comment: Thanks @273K. If the size of float* likes size1 x size2 and the return vector out are 2D vector std::vector<std::vector<float>>, then how to transfer the data from float* to the vector2D

Comment: This is indeed the best. Using `reserve` + `push_back` requires constant size/capacity testing. And allocating up-front + copy will value-initialize everything so you're doing double work with those other suggestions. @KimHee Please don't drastically change your question in comments.

Comment: I know it. However, the way that you are suggestion only work on 1D vector. Am I right? For 2D vector, it maynot work

Comment: Yes of course it won't. A "2D" vector is just a vector that contains other vector _objects_. It bears absolutely no similarities to a 2D array in terms of memory layout.

Comment: @paddy that ignores the possibility of reserve + assign.

Comment: @Taekahn To my knowledge, that is equivalent to the constructor with two iterators.

Comment: `input[size1 + i]` looks odd. You sure you want that `size1` there?  Based on the variable names, I'd expect that to start indexing AFTER the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor for that. I would assume the standard library implementation will make use of as much optimization as it can in that:

```
std::vector<float> CopyFloat2Vector(float* input, int size1) {
    return {input, input+size1};
}
```

Comment: Which one is faster? CopyFloat2Vector or memcpy? Because memcpy needs resize before copy

Comment: @KimHee I have not tested anything, but with this constructor the standard library has all possible information that you have and can implement optimizations just as well or maybe even better. I would expect that it will also just allocate once and then memcpy.

Comment: You should benchmark it if you really care. This should be the fastest, and although `memcpy` can leverage optimizations such as SIMD, so too should a properly-implemented vector constructor for POD types such as float. The benefit is that you avoid doing double the work here because `resize` will value-initialize everything and that might invalidate cache lines.

Comment: @user17732522 I wouldn’t assume that. Last time I looked it (mine anyway) did not take advantage of being able to easily calculate the size and do a single allocation.

Comment: @Taekahn As far as I can tell the major compilers/standard libraries all compile it to a single allocation followed by `memcpy`. Microsoft's implementation uses `memmove` however: https://godbolt.org/z/xsqn5fqWW

Comment: I'd just be cautious of using uniform initialization with `std::vector` as it is easy to accidentally create a vector of 2 elements instead of calling the intended constructor if the arguments happen to be convertible to the element type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, but this is the only way to assure that no copy of the vector is made pre-C++17 (although practically that probably doesn't matter either). Otherwise `return std::vector<float>(input, input+size1);` may be less error-prone.