# Convert float* to 2D vector std::vector<std::vector<float>>

Tags: c++, c++11

Follow the discussion from the question: [Fastest way to transfer/copy data from float* to vector<float>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744879/fastest-way-to-transfer-copy-data-from-float-to-vectorfloat?noredirect=1#comment126790126_71744879) . I want to extend it to 2D vector. Fistly, I post my original code with 2 for loops.

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> ConvertFloatto2DVector(float* input, int size0, int size1) {
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> vector2D;
  for (int sz1 = 0; sz1 < size0; sz1++) {
    std::vector<float> vector1D;

    for (int sz2 = 0; sz2 < size1; sz2++) {
      vector1D.push_back(input[sz1* size1+ sz2]);
    }
    vector2D.push_back(vector1D);
  }
  return vector2D;
}
```

Based on discussion from the above question, we can use a fastest way to convert float* to 1D vector as `std::vector<float> v(input, input + size);`. Is it possible to apply the way to 2D vector size of size1x size2 as my above original code ? And How?

Comment: The smaller vector has extra data (size) so direct mapping will not work. You need to use vector of pair<float,float>

Comment: Is there any reason for a nested vector? If performance is an issue at all, then you probably wouldn't want to split each row in its own allocation. You would just manually map the 2D indices into a `std::vector<float>` as you would with a `float*`.

Comment: you mean that we will flatten the 2D vector to 1D vector?

Comment: Any suggestion or code for your idea @user17732522

Comment: @KimHee Yes, just use a flat 1D array and map 2D indices into it. For the 2D vector construction, just `reserve` followed by `emplace_back` on the outer vector, using the constructor form of the answer in the linked question for the inner vector, is probably fast enough. Each of these vectors needs to allocate anyway which will dwarf any non-optimal construction method of the outer vector.

Comment: Thanks, Could you give me some example code to perform it? I think I can use 1D vector